# std::optional with std::mutex as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++17

We need to pass std::mutex as an argument to a class constructor (when we are testing some test cases). We need this as optional as some times we don't need the mutex. Wrote the below minimal code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <mutex>

class A {
    public:
        A(std::optional <std::mutex &> opLock);
};

A::A(std::optional <std::mutex &> opLock){
    
}

int main() {
    std::mutex lock;
    A a(lock);
}
```

But it is giving below error

```
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional: In instantiation of ‘union std::_Optional_payload_base<std::mutex&>::_Storage<std::mutex&, true>’:
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:241:30:   required from ‘struct std::_Optional_payload_base<std::mutex&>’
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:355:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Optional_payload<std::mutex&, true, false, false>’
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:635:30:   required from ‘struct std::_Optional_base<std::mutex&, true, true>’
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:663:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<std::mutex&>’
jdoodle.cpp:11:41:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:214:15: error: non-static data member ‘std::_Optional_payload_base<std::mutex&>::_Storage<std::mutex&, true>::_M_value’ in a union may not have reference type ‘std::mutex&’
  214 |           _Up _M_value;
      |               ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional: In instantiation of ‘class std::optional<std::mutex&>’:
jdoodle.cpp:11:41:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:679:21: error: static assertion failed
  679 |       static_assert(!is_reference_v<_Tp>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:679:21: note: ‘!(bool)std::is_reference_v<std::mutex&>’ evaluates to false
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:914:7: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘std::mutex&’
  914 |       operator->() const noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/optional:918:7: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘std::mutex&’
  918 |       operator->() noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
jdoodle.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
jdoodle.cpp:17:13: error: ‘A::A(std::optional<std::mutex&>)’ is private within this context
   17 |     A a(lock);
      |             ^
jdoodle.cpp:11:1: note: declared private here
   11 | A::A(std::optional <std::mutex &> opLock){
      | ^
```

Unable to find how to declare the constructor using std::optional std::mutex as parameter.

I tried with std::optional std::mutex also. It is giving different error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <mutex>

class A {
    public:
        A(std::optional <std::mutex> opLock);
};

A::A(std::optional <std::mutex> opLock){
    
}

int main() {
    std::mutex lock;
    A a(lock);
}
```

below error

```
jdoodle.cpp:16:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(std::mutex&)’
   16 |     A a(lock);
      |             ^
jdoodle.cpp:10:1: note: candidate: ‘A::A(std::optional<std::mutex>)’
   10 | A::A(std::optional <std::mutex> opLock){
      | ^
jdoodle.cpp:10:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::mutex’ to ‘std::optional<std::mutex>’
   10 | A::A(std::optional <std::mutex> opLock){
      |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
jdoodle.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(const A&)’
    5 | class A {
      |       ^
jdoodle.cpp:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::mutex’ to ‘const A&’
jdoodle.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(A&&)’
jdoodle.cpp:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::mutex’ to ‘A&&’
```

I thought to try default parameter instead of std::optional. But not sure how to declare the function will will take std::mutex as default parameter.

Comment: I think that it does not make sense to have an optional to a reference type. By the way, it is clearly shown int he error message : `static_assert(!is_reference_v<_Tp>)`.

Comment: I tried with std::optional <std::mutex> also which results in some other error. I just want to send a mutex to the function some times.

Comment: It is weird to pass a mutex to your class. I think that either you should handle locking inside the class and the mutex would be a member or outside the class and thus never passed to the class. Mixing both could be error prone as mutex are not recursive...

Comment: @Phil1970 : The problem is we need to pass the mutex to the member variables (member variables are themselves objects of other classes. Those classes will write to a common file on threads). So we need to pass a mutex from main class to the member variables (which are objects) and those objects when write to a file, lock that mutex.

Comment: By the way as a mutex is not copyable nor moveable, you whole idea is broken. You might argue that you could pass the mutex by pointer or reference but even then it can make the code difficult to use if many classes share a mutex. Making it optional would also make the code more complicated as you would not be easily able to use `lock_guard`.

Comment: Then the mutex should clearly be inside that class that manage writing to the file. Read about SRP (single responsability principle).

Comment: @kadina: "*So we need to pass a mutex from main class to the member variables (which are objects) and those objects when write to a file, lock that mutex.*" It seems really strange that the outside world not only determines whether the lock needs to be obtained or not, it must also provide that lock to the system. But if you really need to do this, just use a pointer.

Comment: @Phil1970 : Not sure whether I explained it correctly. There is a main class which has member variables of classes a, b. When an event occurs, main class will call functions of objects (a and b). Those functions will create threads which will do some file processing and update a common file. As both are different objects on different threads and updating a common file, both should use a common mutex. So this mutex has to be created in main class and to be passed to member variables (objects) which will lock the mutex before updating the files.

Comment: If the mutex is not created in main class and passed to the objects, how the 2 objects will share a common mutex to update the common file.

Comment: @kadina I'd separate out the part that deals with file processing into its own class and have both the members `a` and `b` use this class instead. That way, the class that deals with the file maintains the mutex and it's the only one responsible for handling file ops. Aligns with SRP.

Comment: To make it more concrete : Make a class `C` that has a mutex as a member and handle all operations to that common file. Use object `c`  (of type `C`) to access file from objects `a` and `b`. Move code that access the file into member function of that class `C`. Pass object `c` to object `a` and `b` by reference or some other mean and call the new member functions (that handle locking).